# Why isn't my sign-in form working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a very rudimentary sign-in form. It doesn't have a password or username; simply a text-field for the user's name and a submit button

Here's it's code:

```
<%= form_for :current_user, url: { :controller => 'sessions', :action=>'new' } do |f| %>
<p id='name'>Name:<%= f.text_field :current_user, placeholder: 'First Last', :id => 'current_user' %></p>
<%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

When I submit the name rails gives me this error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SessionsController#new
Couldn't find User without an ID
```

But it receives the correct parameters because it includes

```
"current_user"=>{"name"=>"John Doe"}
```

This is what i want it to receive, but what I'm having trouble with is properly defining the action to actually set the current_user to John Doe.

So here's what I have in the controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new
  @current_user = User.find(params[:name])
  redirect_to '/calendar'
end

end
```

All I want it to do is set the variable @current_user to the user in the database named John Doe. So what I need my action to do is match up the submitted name John Doe to John Doe in the database. But I don't know how to do this, so any advice would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a `nil` to your `User.find` method, because you're incorrectly referencing your `name` parameter.

What you need to do instead is either of the following:

```
User.find(params[:current_user])
```

**OR**

```
User.find_by_name(params[:current_user][:name])
```

The code you're using:

```
User.find(params[:name])
```

...is invalid because the `params` hash contains another hash called `current_user`, in which the `name` parameter appears, hence:

```
params[:current_user][:name]
         \/            \/
'current_user' => { 'name' => 'John Doe' }
```